# Alternatives to "Global variable"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

My add-on made with Google Apps Script has a bunch of variables, around 60, which are used in 5 different functions. So these variables logically have to be global.

However 20 of 60 variables require `ScriptApp.AuthMode` other than NONE. I do not want to copy paste them into all 5 functions, and would like to keep them kinda global, however they result in a script failure while authorization is not yet granted.

Whats the best practice in this case to keep those variables accessible by functions, yet not exactly global?

As Adam H noted, the question is very broad, so I'll be more specific:

1. put global variables in a if statement
2. add function that returns these variables
3. move them from global to every function that needs them

Which is the best?

Comment: This is a very broad question that doesn't have a specific answer and might result in some downvotes for you. You could checkout [namespacing](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/) and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: Global variables are usually not a great idea. It would be better to have only one global variable holding an object containing all your variables. Or better yet, look into something like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)

Comment: Use the designated `PropertiesService` and `CacheService`. Also note that defining "expensive" globals is really bad in practice, because every global in Apps Script is evaluated for each new instance invocation (for example, each time `google.script.run` is executed from an open sidebar). So I truly doubt you want to have global variables that require LIMITED or FULL in order to execute.

Comment: @tehhowch well getProperties also requires authMode.Limited unless it's running in onInstall() trigger.

Comment: @SamTyurenkov yes but inside a function you can use if statements to determine which case you are in, rather than assume and fail :)

Comment: @tehhowch yes, but those variables are not in function yet, they are global, as I mentioned earlier. I need to get this spreadsheet id in particular, and many other variables depend on that ID as well. Is there a way to check authMode outside of the function? So spreadsheet ID is used in all of the functions actually. And I can't use getActive(), because it won't get ID for time-driven functions.

Comment: @SamTyurenkov perhaps you don't yet understand what is being suggested: write a function that creates your config object. From your entry functions, call that function, and access the "config" object it returns. E.g. `SpreadsheetApp.openById(config.wbId)`

Comment: `openById()` also requires authMode.Limited

This works:
`function onInstall (e) {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID', e.source.getId()); 
  onOpen(e);
}` This doesn't:
 `var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178016/discussion-between-sam-tyurenkov-and-tehhowch).

Comment: @|'-'| I have it, but it fails to appear because of the global variable that requests a spreadsheet ID, still have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way should be:

Option 2: add function that returns these variables

Reasons:

- With a function, you can have reusablity. And in future if a variable needs change in it's value then you need to make change at only one place.
- We can not go with option 3 as it will be unnecessarily adding same code again and again.
- We can not go with option 1 and leave the variables global as this can allow in one to overwrite the values of the variable.

Note:

Even the function can be oven written so use js closure to save your variables from getting update by undesirable sources or hooks.

Answer (score -1):

This is a heavily opinion based topic but here is what I would do, take it for what its worth.

```js
// create your namespace
var myApp = (function() {
  // variables that are local to your app
  let myVariable;

  // functions that are exposed by your app
  return {
    myFunction: function() {
      // you can reference all the variables defined above here
      return myVariable;
    },
    // your initialization function (or a poor mans constructor)
    init: function(varValue) {
      // store the values passed in here
      myVariable = varValue;
    }
  };

})();

// Init your app with your variables
myApp.init('Random Value');

// Now you just call your functions
console.log(myApp.myFunction())
```

Comment: This is not really applicable to the Google Apps Script execution environment. (`let` is not a valid keyword in Google Apps Script either.)

Comment: Nowadays, using V8 runtime, Google Apps Script supports `let`